# Can I send mail using Javascript and jquery without a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, gmail, html-email

I can use only javascirpt and jquery.

My customer said without server and using javascript and jquery can send email from gmail SMTP.

Gmail SMTP surpport only use javascript and jquery can send Email? and without server?

I want send email the mail template(html) in dynamic value (without Server!)

I tried this URL content.

https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server#how

But I have to send an e-mail with the entered ID.
This ID is dynamic value.

Comment: Not that I know of. You will need a server to connect to the Mail Server. And even if you can, you shouldn't do that. Since the connection to the mail server is quite important and any code in client side can be looked at so that connection is compromised and that is quite dangerous

Comment: The answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send an email direct from front-end using JavaScript, Jquery or any front-end framework/library externally using server or back-end. because your credentials are open to all and there are so many factors work behind that...

An option is to let each user use his or her sociable mail server, by doing a mailto: connection, which allows you to define the header data & including a quasi-header called 'body', which sets the content you require to pass in the message body.

You can Send Using:-

There are also some parameters to add:

However, you can append parameters to email like the following:-

Here are some parameters you can pass in the mail you want to send from front-end

`mailto`:-add recipients,

`note`:- if you want to add multiple recipients then add comma-separated as mentioned in the example.

`&cc`=    to add CC recipients,

`&bcc`=    to add BCC recipients,

`&subject`=   to add mail subject,

`&body`=       to add mail body,

Example:-

```
<a href="mailto:sendMe1@example.com?cc=sendMecc@example.com?bcc=sendMebcc@example.com?subject=Mail-SubJect
  &body=Mail-Body....">
Send Me Email from Front-end
</a>
```

Some customer-service providers provide you to send an email with the help of their service [smtpjs](https://www.smtpjs.com/), [formspree](https://formspree.io/), [emailjs](http://www.emailjs.com/), 
[Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), but this is not practical plus trusted.